# Rails 6 - API authentication using Devise (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, token, access-token

I currently have a productive web based Rails 6 application using devise for authentication.

I now have the requirement to implement API access to the same webapp.

Ideally:

- There would be a separate auth link. (i.e. web access through http://<app_url>/users/sign_in and api login through http://<app_url>/api/v1/login
- The intention is to receive user & password on the login and reply, once it's valid, a token with a certain validity (still uncertain if this should be in terms of days or weeks)

The api access with a valid token, should result in bypassing devise and granting the access.

I have implemented more than one solution available in forums, but none worked on Rails 6.

The options I have tried include using devise-jwt gem.

Any help on directions to overcome this are highly appreciated. I'm stuck in this scenario for a few days now.

**Edit**

I have tried some online options, but either bc I have a limited skill with rails or bc these don't work on Rails 6, I'm not getting any feasible state that I can use to move forward.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nicolas. The question is if there would be some sample available that allows me to generate a token and use devise at the same time.

Comment: What is the problem with the devise-jwt gem?